# Como sobreponer un uiview en swift

Tags: swift

tengo un uiview y dentro del uiview un tableview, intente hacer algo como esto: https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/StretchableTableViewHeader-Swift

lo que pasa es que cuando le doy clic al uiview, también le da click a la celda del tableview, que podría hacer para que al darle clic al uiview, solo le de clic a ese y no a la celda de la tabla cuando esa celda esta por abajo ?

gracias

Comment: Si deseas que te ayudemos deber proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes desactivar los eventos de touch de la tabla usando

```
self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

y cuando quieras que vuelva a reconocer los eventos de touch le pones true a esa propiedad

Comment: Bueno pero esque no deseo desactivarla, mira te explico más a detalle, tengo mi View controller y dentro puseotro View y dentro de ese nuevo View puse un tableview, para poder poner un Parallax header y cuando llegara a cierto tamaño se mantenga en ese tamaño, pero al momento de dar click al UIView (header) al row que esté por abajo se le da click pero no deseo que haga eso ya que en el header pondré botones, 


Saludos

Comment: Pues lo mejor será que pongas el código que has hecho

Comment: coloca una foto o código, pero tal vez en el didSelectAtItem tienes activado algo o si tienes el referenceSizeForHeaderInSection